# Using SED to substitute regex match with variable value

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with following lines:

```
2022-Nov-23
2021-Jul-14
```

I want to replace the month with its number, my script should accept the date as an argument, and I added these variables to it:

```
Jan=01
Feb=02
Mar=03
Apr=04
May=05
Jun=06
Jul=07
Aug=08
Sep=09
Oct=10
Nov=11
Dec=12
```

How can I match the month name in the string with regex and substitute it based on the variables? here is what I have for now:

echo "$1" | sed 's/(\w{3})/${\1}/'

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not `awk`, e.g. `awk -F- -vOFS=- 'BEGIN { m["Jan"]="01"; … } { $2 = m[$2] ; print }'`?

Comment: …or multiple `sed` operations: `sed 's/Jan/01/g;s/Feb/02/g;…'`?

Comment: …or if you really want to define the months in a file you could source and export them (e.g. `set -a; . file ; set +a`) and then use `ENVIRON` in `awk`.

Comment: The first option works but it prints the months from Jan to Sep as a single digit, I mean 7 instead of 07

Comment: I edited the first comment to use strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file called `months` containing:

```bash
Jan=01
Feb=02
Mar=03
Apr=04
May=05
Jun=06
Jul=07
Aug=08
Sep=09
Oct=10
Nov=11
Dec=12
```

And a script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

sub() (
  set -a
  . "${0%/*}/months"
  awk -F- -vOFS=- '{ $2 = ENVIRON[$2]; print }'
)

printf 2022-Nov-23 | sub
printf 2021-Jul-14 | sub
```

The output is:

```
2022-11-23
2021-07-14
```

Answer (score 1):

You might convert your data into sed script, that is create say file `mon2num.sed` with following content

```
s/Jan/01/
s/Feb/02/
s/Mar/03/
s/Apr/04/
s/May/05/
s/Jun/06/
s/Jul/07/
s/Aug/08/
s/Sep/09/
s/Oct/10/
s/Nov/11/
s/Dec/12/
```

and having `file.txt` with content as follows

```
2022-Nov-23
2021-Jul-14
```

you might do

```
sed -f mon2num.sed file.txt
```

which gives output

```
2022-11-23
2021-07-14
```